# How to manipulate thermal relaxation noise in Qiskit model?

Tags: noise, qiskit

I am trying to experiment with various values of T1 and T2 parameters in thermal relaxation noise.

```
IBMQ.load_account()
provider = IBMQ.get_provider(group="open")
backend_to_mimic = provider.get_backend(name="ibmq_quito")
noise_model = NoiseModel.from_backend(backend_to_mimic)

backend_properties = backend_to_mimic.properties()
t1s = [backend_properties.t1(i) for i in range(5)]
t2s = [backend_properties.t2(i) for i in range(5)]

Increasing T1s and T2s for all qubits by a factor of 10
t1s = [10*t for t in t1s] 
t2s = [10*t for t in t2s]

basis_gates = noise_model.basis_gates
for i, t in enumerate(zip(t1s, t2s)):
    tre = thermal_relaxation_error(t1=t[0], t2=t[1], time=np.inf)
    noise_model.add_quantum_error(error=tre, instructions=['id', 'reset', 'rz', 'sx', 'x'], qubits=[i]) #The gates are ibmq_quito's basis gates except cx which is a two qubit gate

coupling_map = backend_to_mimic.configuration().coupling_map
backend.set_options(coupling_map=coupling_map)

backend.set_options(basis_gates=basis_gates)
backend.set_options(noise_model=noise_model)

instance = QuantumInstance(backend,optimization_level=0, basis_gates=basis_gates)
```

Now, when I do the above and calculate the expectation values of an operator on instance, I get results much worse than what I get with ibmq_quito's noise model. I would expect that since I am increasing the values of relaxation time and dephasing time, the the results should be better. What am I doing wrong?